# using href hash inside article within one page design

Tags: javascript, jquery, href, vertical-scrolling

I'm working on website (parallax design), I have many sections 1,2,3,4 ... in the fourth section i have a long paragraph (article) with scroll inside the article div only (not the hole section).. with navigation menu to the headings of the article

```
<section class="one"> content .. </section>
<section class="two"> content .. </section>
<section class="three"> content .. </section>
<section class="four">
       <div class="content">
           <div class="article with-vertical-scroll">
               <ul>
                  <li><a href="#part1">Part 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#part2">Part 2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#part3">Part 3</a></li>
               </ul>
               <h2 id="part1"><p>.....</p></h2>
               <h2 id="part2"><p>.....</p></h2>
               <h2 id="part3"><p>.....</p></h2>
           </div>
       </div>
</section>
```

when I click on any link, at the first click, the link will take me to section One, then i return to section four and click again and links works good and take me to the headings.. I tried to use jQuery with scrollTop, and I tried to disable default event when I click `e.preventDefault();` but didn't work.

```
$('a').click(function(e){
//e.preventDefault();
   target = $(this).attr('href');
   $('.article').scrollTop(target);
});
```

Comment: You want smooth scroll to different section? what code you used show the jquery code

Comment: not in the section, inside article (article menu navigation) like links in wikipedia

Comment: @user3003810 as you can see in [docs](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/#scrollTop2), `.scrollTop(value)` requires `Number`, not `String`.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry for that, but how can i solve this problem without jQuery ? or with it ! @Regent

Comment: @user3003810 well, something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w67yj552/), I suppose.

Comment: Ok, your example works fine, but in my website not work ! no action occur when I click, when I write console.log(targetTop); it types 2288 ..

Comment: @user3003810 is 2288 correct value for element's offset top? I don't see any problems with my code, especially concerning that you got `targetTop` value.

Comment: yes this value is correct according to the window, because when I click on another link this value is changed and this is great ! but nothing happened on my website, i don't have any idea why this happened

Comment: @user3003810 neither do I. Have you any other `<a>` event handlers? If so, you can try to replace `e.preventDefault();` with `return false;` as the last line in event handler to check whether stopping event propagation will solve the problem. [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/w67yj552/1/).

Comment: thank you very much for your help, the problem is I'm using jScrollPane plugin which block the default scrolling for the div and it has APIs to achieve the problem !@Regent